# Facebook add profile box for iframe app

Tags: facebook, iframe, profile

I have an iframe app that only really has a canvas page.  I need to integrate a profile box with this app.  A lot of tutorials have you editing the Default FBML under profile box settings, but that option doesn't exist anymore.  I'm curious how to set default FBML for my iframe app and how to allow the user to add my app's profile box to their profile.

Thanks.
-Troy

Answer (score 1):

I'm hitting a similar situation.  Its clear a profile box cannot contain an iframe (or even fb:iframe).  It also cannot contain external script links.

It looks like you can use the FBJS to ajax in some content, but overall you should be using the profile box to "enter" your canvas.